# Get File Path in local System in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to get the client local path without hard coding in JavaScript.
I used the below code to get the path, but it is retrieved from the server. 
Can someone help me how to get local file path in JavaScript.

```
recordPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
                                          HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("saveFile")));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "local path" ? is it `%temp%` directory in windows?

Comment: I mean local drives path like D:\, E:\ etc not %temp%. @KNeerajLal

Comment: Is it for storing a value?

Comment: it is actually to read ActiveX control from server and to store it in our Machine.

Comment: Use can use `cookies` to store data on the Local Machine. `http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp`

Comment: I think cookies can store the data. but unfortunately we cannot make ActiveX Control to store in it.

Comment: Try this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370960/auto-install-activex

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get an absolute file path via javascript. You can only get file paths relative to the server page.

```
location.pathname;
location.hostname;
```

All absolute paths should be handled on the back end, and should not be hard coded into js, which is freely visible to the user.

Comment: Thank you. 
but is it possible to get absolute paths in any other scripting languages like vbscript?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not allow showing drive paths. You can try vbScript for it.
Check This Out :

[How to get Hard Disk number from drive letter using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955673/how-to-get-hard-disk-number-from-drive-letter-using-vbscript)